# ZFS send/recv full snapshot

Tags: linux, backup, zfs, snapshot, zfsonlinux

I have been backing up my ZFS pool in Server A to Server B (backup server) via `zfs send/recv`, and using daily incremental snapshots.

Due to hardware issues, the ZFS pool in Server A is now gone - and I want to restore/recover it asap.

Currently the snapshot list in my Server B is as follows :

```
zfs49/tank@2021Nov301705   368G      -     3.52T  -
zfs49/tank@2021Dec011705  65.2G      -     3.52T  -
zfs49/tank@2021Dec021705  66.4G      -     3.52T  -
zfs49/tank@2021Dec031705     0B      -     3.52T  -
```

where `zfs49/tank@2021Dec031705` is the latest.

I would like to send back the whole pool (including the snapshots) back to Server A, but I'm unsure of the exact command to run.

Question : On Server B, will doing `zfs send zfs49/tank@2021Dec031705 | ssh <Server A host ip> zfs recv tank` be sufficient to receive the full ZFS pool + all the snapshots (so I can continue incremental send/recv backups) on Server A?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work, as long as `zfs49/tank` doesn't exist on Server A.

I would only use a couple more options, especially `-R` on `send` to replicate the whole pool:

```shell
zfs send -R zfs49/tank@2021Dec031705 \
  | ssh ServerA zfs recv -vusF dest_pool/tank
```

While we're here, thanks to `recv -s`, you can now resume interrupted transfers with:

```shell
zfs send -v -t "the-token" \
  | ssh ServerA zfs recv -vusF dest_pool/tank
```

where the token is on the receiving side:

```shell
zfs get receive_resume_token dest_pool/tank
```